# Android - Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt unable to load com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ToolsLocator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, r.java-file

I'm having a issue with eclipse that when I start the eclipse then it shows me a error in a message box "Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ToolsLocator". When i click OK then the screen then here you can see a snapshot of it (Image link http://postimg.org/image/tixjg91gp/full/)
The things I have tried are: Reinstalling Eclipse+ADT, Restarting Eclipse+PC, Searching about it and found no results.
Please if you know what it is then please post your answer under this, Thank you.
Another issue that I'm having is [Android - Eclipse project making and R file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260776/android-eclipse-project-making-and-r-file-error/)